# Move javascript outside of html in Flask

Tags: javascript, html, web, flask, frontend

I have a working Flask project. HTML file with 2 scripts:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dropdown").on("show.bs.dropdown", function(event){
            var x = $(event.relatedTarget).text(); // Get the button text
            <!--alert("You clicked on: " + x); -->
        });
    });
...</script>

<script>
window.onload = function () {

var allDates = [{% for item in allDates %}
                  "{{item}}",
              {% endfor %}]
    ...
    </script>
```

I wanted to move the scripts externally for better organization of the code. 
I've opened file called history.js inside the static folder, and posted there the inside parts of the scripts (Without the  tags)

Then I tried to include it in my history.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/history.js') }}"></script>
```

It didn't succeed. The JS part won't activate.

The files structure is good, 
Proj-Name 
    | templates (contains the history.html, also extends base.html file)
    | static (contains the history.js)

What am I missing? I've tried to include the javascript part in several methods and still couldn't find out what is wrong.

Comment: please post console output from developer options of your browser. It should be showing some error. This issue is most likely reference issue. Please post project structure as well

Comment: Ok it helped, I have this line in my javascript file:
var allDates = [{% for item in allDates %}
                  "{{item}}",
              {% endfor %}]

So the HTML file knows 'allDates' ( render_template('history.html') ... ) 

But when I export the js to another file, it doesn't know the variables I got from Flask. 

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Ok problem solved - I made the initialization of the global variables inside script in the html, and all of the rest js code inside the history.js file. Thanks you helped me figure it out